# Pentaho Max Column width error while trying to output an excel from xaction

Tags: java, excel, max, pentaho

I've managed to set up a sucessful working enviroment using 3 pentaho tools for my Database.
A kettle transformation: which queries from a JNDI.
A pentaho reporting: which organizes and outputs the data given by the transformation.
And an Action Secuence xaction which manages the parameters and puts online the report solution.

Everything seems to work fine, once i put online my report and i enter some input in the parameters and then it submits the form with almost any report format: text/html, pdf and cvs.

But when I try to submit an excel output (application/vnd.ms-excel) I get the following error:

> The Pentaho BI Platform reported an error while running an action
>   sequence
>
> Possible Causes: RuntimeContext.ERROR_0017 - [es_18] Activity failed
>   to execute  Action Sequence:BillingReport.xaction Execution Stack:
>   EXECUTING ACTION: Pentaho Report (SimpleReportingComponent) Loop Index
>   (1-based):0 Error Time:miércoles 5 de septiembre de 2012 12H18' VET
>   Error Type:ActionExecutionException Session ID:joe Instance
>   Id:65ad1224-f779-11e1-a34f-b53c1ce91064 Action
>   Class:SimpleReportingComponent Action Description:Pentaho Report

Even with no fields in the .prpt file it keeps showing that same error (i also refreshed biserver using administration console with every change i make).
If I check what happened in catalina.out log I get a bunch of java exception traces but there's a line that shows:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The maximum column width for an
>   individual cell is 255 characters.

I'm not sure but it seems like a jira issue related with apache/tomcat function called setColumnWidth.

Any Ideas?